# How to exclude user related object from DacPac file

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, ssdt-2017

I am creating `SSDT` project using visual studio, I want to remove the users-related object from the `dacpac` file before deploying it.

I tried to exclude objects from the 'Advanced Deployment Settings' but as you can see on the following screenshot, all options are disabled. 
could you please advise on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mark `DROP objects in target but not in project` before you go in `Advanced` you will get them enabled:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this one is ok. Please I have another issue if you can help in it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61650390/cant-deploy-dacpac-on-azure-devops-cd